# Refresh data in table view in a view controller that contains multiple table views

Tags: iphone, ios, uibarbuttonitem, uibarbuttonitemstyle

I want to add a refresh bar button in my view controller

```
UIBarButtonItem *refreshButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refreshTable)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = refreshButton;
```

and the refreshtable function is :

```
- (void) refreshTable
{
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
     NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://....../fastnews.php"]];
     [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
});
}
```

and the fetch data function is:

```
    -(void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData
{
   NSError *error;
   NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
  fastResults = [json objectForKey:@"nodes"];
  [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

If I had two table view in my view controller, and I want when I click on the refresh button, just the first table to be reloaded,

[image]

I put the same you code above, but it doesn't work here! should I do something else?
I do something like this:
[image]

which refreshButton is : `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem  *refreshButton;`

Comment: Give the name of the tableview and call the reloadData. Means if you declared your tableview like `IBOutlet UITableView *secondTable;` call like `[secondTable reloadData];`

Comment: Have you solved the issue ?

Comment: that's what exactly I did, but not working, shall I do something in storyboard property like rely outlet or something else?

Comment: Which tableview you want to refresh ,On pressing that reload button ?

Comment: the above one, I rename it fastTableView, In implementing this table , I rely it by another view controller `    if (secondController == nil) {
  secondController = [[FastNewsListViewController alloc] init];
 }
 
 [fastTableView setDataSource:secondController];
 [fastTableView setDelegate:secondController];
 
 secondController.view = secondController.tableView;`

Comment: @CarinaM : You have two tableviews.Simply give me the answer which tableview (1st one or 2nd one) you want to reload on that reloadButton click ?

Comment: look when I press on the refresh button nothing is refreshed otherwise, when I push a cell from this table and come back to the view controller, I see that the table is refreshed!

Comment: @Vin the first one which its name is fastTableView

Comment: Use my Answer and... `UIBarButtonItem *refreshButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refreshTable:1)];`

Comment: @Vin thank you :), it is solved now

Comment: @CarinaM: If my answer helped you to solve the issue then pls accept it or if you found any other solution then add as an answer.

Comment: @Vin yes I know, but I didn't use yours, in fact I found a simple mistake in my code and now is resolved, thank you

Comment: @CarinaM: With pleasure. Good to know that you solved it yourself. :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to assign tag values. Just create separate properties for both tables and you can use the table name to call `reloadData` for first table only.

Comment: that's what I have: `[secondController.tableView reloadData];`, but still not working, which secondcontroller is the name of the table I want to reload data

Comment: `    if (secondController == nil) {
  secondController = [[FastNewsListViewController alloc] init];
 }
 
 [fastTableView setDataSource:secondController];
 [fastTableView setDelegate:secondController];
 
 secondController.view = secondController.tableView;`

Comment: which FastNewsListViewController is another view controller I implemented which contains the same data of the table I want to reload it but has more number of cells in sections.

Comment: @CarinaM You made me confuse by introducing this code which is completely new than your question. I would appreciate if you edit your question to combine your both controllers and tables.

Comment: In fact, my code is complicated, because this is the first application I did, and i am new in IOS application, so execuse me if I have mistakes, and I am thankfull for your support :), thank you very much